# onBlur Javascript event with check if an element has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur, onfocus

I am trying to find a solution to a simple thing, that looks complex!

I have a textarea where users can update their status.
Underneath it I have a checkbox (ex: for the user to choose to tweet the status or no).

What I try to do is this:
1/ When the textera get the focus, the textarea expands, for that it's fine.

2/ When the textarea loose focus, so when the user clicks out of it, it collapse. That's fine too...

The only problem is that if the user click on the checkbox, the textarea collapse too but I want to prevent it.

It should collapse and execute the function on blur, but not if the user try to interact with the checkbox.

I set up an example on this page: http://favosaurus.com/dev/onblur.php

thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Your link is just a blank page. I though onblur meant that the element has lost focus? If a user clicks outside the element, then it will have lost focus.

Comment: @Michael Robinson but he wants the textarea to PRETEND it hasn't lost focus (and presumably gain focus back) if and only if the checkbox is clicked

Comment: Sorry I had a session verification on that page, removed it so it can be accessible by anyone. Still didn't figure it out pretty simple and hard in the same time...

The best is to see the example. When a user enter a text the textarea expands. Fine. If there is some texts and the user clicks outside, the textarea doesn't collapse. Fine too. It collapses only if the textarea is empty... but the problem is if it's empty but the user click on the checkbox, it shouldn't collapse :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use Javascript.

Pseudocode:

```
if input blur,  and checkbox not clicked:

     do normal blur action.

else:

     process checkbox click
     focus input again
```

Comment: Does this take into account the fact that the blur event on the textbox occurs before the focus event on the checkbox?